# Get Field order from a list view : Javascript object model

Tags: javascript, list-view, view, jsom

I am getting the fields of a list view using the javascript object model

```
view.get_viewFields()
```

However, this does not return the fields in order which they are configured in the view. It just returns the schema xml with the internal names and we can read the field names using the "get_item()" method. I have observed that the order that is returned is the order in which the columns were created in the list.

Is there a way to read the current order of fields in list view using javascript object model ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this information? maybe there is an other way to do what you want to do.

Comment: i have written a sharepoint hosted app where user selects list items and clicks custom ribbon action app. SP hosted app opens in modal dialog and displays the records in table which then can be printed. If the order of the columns is changed in the view, app does not present columns in that order.

Comment: for me, the get_viewFields() method returns the order in which the fields appear in the view, not the order they were created as you said.

Comment: did you change the order of the fields in the view after creating the columns ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try using REST query as below:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'></script>
<script>
var xmlString;
try {
        //REST Query to get the display form url 
        jQuery.ajax(
        {
            url: "http://<URL>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'<GUID>')/Views(guid'<GUID>')",
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                           xmlString = data.d.ListViewXml;
                            },
            error: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert("Error while getting Display form url");
            }
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }

var xmlDoc =$.parseXML(xmlString);
$xml = $(xmlDoc);
$viewFields = $xml.find("ViewFields");
if($viewFields[0].childNodes.length > 0){

    for(var i=0; i < $viewFields[0].childNodes.length; i++){
        alert($viewFields[0].childNodes[i].attributes[0].textContent);
        }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps to resolve your query!!